# Daterangepicker for Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm coming back with a very simple questions, yet I am not able to solve it on my own...

I found a powerful Daterangepicker in Javascript : http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex5 . As I have never learned js, I would like to know how to pass the start and end dates out of the widget to the views.py file... The few hints I got came from this topic : [Django and date range picker component for Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518284/django-and-date-range-picker-component-for-twitter-bootstrap) which only provides the code for Django and not the js.

Many thanks !

Comment: Ok, I found the solution ! Maybe it will be useful for someone else, so I paste it here :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the function in http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex5

```
function(start, end, label) {}
```

Use `AJAX` requests to send this data to server(view).Something like

```
function(start, end, label) {
    $.post("url",
    {
       "start":start,
       "end": end
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data sent);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution ! Maybe it will be useful for someone else, so I paste it here :

```
$.ajax({
   url:'/',
   type : "POST", 
   data: {start : 'start', end : 'end'},
   success: function(response){},
   complete: function(){},
   error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError){}
   });
```